# On the longevity of prophets?

Tags: prophets, authenticity

I've heard various accounts that various prophets were extremely long lived. For instance a brother at my mosque told me that Moses was ~1200 years old, and had been a prophet for ~300. I've never once encountered a solid, authentic account of this sort of longevity for any of the prophets.

Is there anything verifiable that says certain prophets lived longer than others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/did-prophets-prior-to-muhammad-live-for-hundreds-of-years

Comment: while the above question is related, the context is different. The answer in that question is not of good quality. This question is more specific to what is asked about

Comment: Salman Farsi (an Iranian companion of prophet) had life of around 300 years or more. this has high validity in different history books.

Comment: @Ahmadi would you mind posting that with citations?

Comment: @Pureferret [here](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/bookview.html?BookID=45266&BookArticleID=23642) 16 references is mentioned with different ages around 300 even 500 years. but this article finally concludes most probably his age was 250. he is not the only. such people are called معمرین  (long ages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Noah**

Lived for 950 years.

> And We certainly sent Noah to his people, and **he remained among them a thousand years minus fifty years**, and the flood seized them while they were wrongdoers. 
>   (Al-'Ankabut 29:14)

**Adam**

Lived for 940 years. Not sure how strong this hadith is; all the sites I find it on say it is sound, but none of those sites are reliable, mostly personal websites and blogs, but they all refer to the same hadith.

> .... Now Adam was reckoning for himself, and  when the angel of death came to him, Adam said to him, "You have come before your time. **A thousand years have been recorded for me**." He replied, "**Certainly, but you appointed sixty years** for your descendant David." Then he denied, and his descendants denied; and he forgot, and his descendants forgot. The Prophet said that from that day orders were given that a document be drawn up and witnesses be produced.
>   Transmitted by Tirmidhi.
>   (Hadith Sunan Al-Tirmidhi 4662)

Comment: About Noah --peace be upon him-- according to Quran he was among his people as prophet for 950 years so that his life was even longer, I have seen some Ahadith telling that he has lived for more than 2000 years, maybe 2000 is an exaggerated number but also 950 is the length of his prophecy! Also about Adam and his 60 years gift to David peace be upon them, it is also stated in Shia Ahadith!